# Anomoly with io.compression.zipfile in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, compression

I'm using a powershell script to automate the archiving of a directory, and its sub-directories. I'm using a very simple

```
    Add-Type -AssemblyName "system.io.compression.filesystem"
    [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($d, $destinationFilename)
```

For the most part, this is doing precisely what I need it to do; but lately there is a problem with empty sub-directories. These empty sub-directories are somehow getting compressed as files, rather than directories.

1. First, has anyone else encountered this?
2. Is the problem related to this .Net API, or is there an enviromental issue at play?
3. Should I use a different version of the ::CreateFromDirectory function?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Considered https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive ?

Comment: I'm game to give this a try. Thanks! Does it use something other than the .Net framework library?

Comment: Can you describe a sample directory structure for which this occurs? Can't seem to replicate

Comment: Is there anything special about the directories that get added as files?  Is it only when compressing files on a network share?  Is it only files with specific characters in the name?  Is it only when you run the script from a specific server?  Have you tried specifying the full name of the assembly (e.g., `Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'`)?

Comment: Hi Everyone,The directory structure is one a dedicated extra drive; but it is not a shared resource. The structure is deep, but not complicated. D:\Parent\..., where the empty directories are located two or more levels down from the parent directory. There isn't a particular pattern to where the empty directories are located. Note, in several cases, even though the directories are empty, they are required. Not having them has interferred with other processes.

Comment: There aren't anything special about the directories. They don't have any kind of special protections or anything like that. The directory mentioned in my last message is not part of  network share, but on a dedicated drive. The script is being run on the same server where the problem is occurring. The scripts are located in D:\Scripts. No, I had not tried the full name assembly, but I can try that. This is a production server, so I'll have to wait for a window, but I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this script by Bryan which does what it says and it should meet your requirement too.

There are lot of parameters which you can utilize like compression type, timestamp, confirm

```
# Purpose: Creates a .zip file of a file or folder.
#
# Sample: zipstuff.ps1 -target "C:\Projects\wsubi" -zip_to "C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\wsubi" [-compression fast] [-timestamp] [-confirm]
#
# Params:
# -target: The file or folder you would like to zip.
#
# -zip_to: The location where the zip file will be created. If an old version
# exists, it will be deleted.
#
# -compression (optional): Sets the compression level for your zip file. Options:
# a. fast - Higher process speed, larger file size (default option).
# b. small - Slower process speed, smaller file size.
# c. none - Fastest process speed, largest file size.
#
# -add_timestamp (optional): Applies a timestamp to the .zip file name.
# By default, no timestamp is used.
#
# -confirm (optional): When provided, indicates that you would like to be
# prompted when the zip process is finished.
#
# |Info|

[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
  [string]$target,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
  [string]$zip_to,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)]
  [ValidateSet("fast","small","none")]
  [string]$compression,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=3)]
  [bool]$timestamp,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=4)]
  [bool]$confirm
)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
function DeleteFileOrFolder
{ Param([string]$PathToItem)

  if (Test-Path $PathToItem)
  {
    Remove-Item ($PathToItem) -Force -Recurse;
  }
}

function DetermineCompressionLevel{
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\WINDOWS\System32\zipfldr.dll')
Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
  $CompressionToUse = $null;

  switch($compression)
  {
    "fast" {$CompressionToUse = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Fastest}
    "small" {$CompressionToUse = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal}
    "none" {$CompressionToUse = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::NoCompression}
    default {$CompressionToUse = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Fastest}
  }

  return $CompressionToUse;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
Write-Output "Starting zip process...";

if ((Get-Item $target).PSIsContainer)
{
  $zip_to = ($zip_to + "\" + (Split-Path $target -Leaf) + ".zip");
}
else{

  #So, the CreateFromDirectory function below will only operate on a $target
  #that's a Folder, which means some additional steps are needed to create a
  #new folder and move the target file into it before attempting the zip process. 
  $FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($target);
  $NewFolderName = ($zip_to + "\" + $FileName)

  DeleteFileOrFolder($NewFolderName);

  md -Path $NewFolderName;
  Copy-Item ($target) $NewFolderName;

  $target = $NewFolderName;
  $zip_to = $NewFolderName + ".zip";
}

DeleteFileOrFolder($zip_to);

if ($timestamp)
{
  $TimeInfo = New-Object System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo;
  $CurrentTimestamp = Get-Date -Format $TimeInfo.SortableDateTimePattern;
  $CurrentTimestamp = $CurrentTimestamp.Replace(":", "-");
  $zip_to = $zip_to.Replace(".zip", ("-" + $CurrentTimestamp + ".zip"));
}

$Compression_Level = (DetermineCompressionLevel);
$IncludeBaseFolder = $false;

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" );
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($target, $zip_to, $Compression_Level, $IncludeBaseFolder);

Write-Output "Zip process complete.";

if ($confirm)
{
  write-Output "Press any key to quit ...";
  $quit = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown");
}
```

**Usage:**

```
zipstuff.ps1 -target "C:\Projects\wsubi" -zip_to "C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\wsubi" [-compression fast] [-timestamp] [-confirm]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Ranadip, I really appreciate this example. I'm going to try this out now. Have you experienced the problem I encountered? If so, did this script fix the problem?

Comment: @halciber: I know the limitations for the dot net thats why I started using the `zipfldr.dll`. If it is not there , you can download it externally and can give the path like I gave in the script `C:\WINDOWS\System32\zipfldr.dll` :)